# Simple recoding in R

Tags: r

Im trying to recode multiple values in a column, it should be very simple.
recode the values -9,-8,-7 to NA in variable "var"
the stata equivalent is `recode var_name (-9=.)(-8=.)(-7=.)(-2=.)(-1=.)`

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear, as the Stata example includes -2 and -1. What values, precisely, do you want to recode? Is it from -9 to -1 inclusive?

Comment: recode the values -9, -8, -7,-2,-1 to NA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a data frame, `mydata`, with the values in column `var`, you could use `ifelse()` to generate the new values. Here they are stored in column `y` but you could alter column `var` if desired.

```
mydata$y <- ifelse(mydata$var %in% c(-9, -8, -7, -2, -1), NA, mydata$var)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the library `naniar` for that.

```
> df <- data.frame(col1=c(-9, -8, 2, 4))
> df <- replace_with_na(df, replace=list(col1=c(-9, -8)))
> print (df$col1)
[1] NA NA  2  4
```

Reference on `naniar` [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/naniar/vignettes/replace-with-na.html).

Answer (score 1):

```r
your.data$var[ your.data$var %in% c( -9, -8, -7,-2,-1 ) ] <- NA
```

Find the ones matching your numbers and insert NA there